# Find a Value in Two Dimensional Array on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, find

I declared my Array:

```
Dim invoice_discountitems(100, 100) As String
```

Set Values into array:

```
For i As Int16 = 0 To data_set.Tables("discount_items").Rows.Count - 1
    invoice_discountitems(i, 1) = data_set.Tables("discount_items").Rows(0).Item("item_code")
    invoice_discountitems(i, 2) = data_set.Tables("discount_items").Rows(0).Item("discountitem_average")
Next
```

Now I try to find a single value:

```
Dim res As String
res = Array.IndexOf(invoice_discountitems, "FO1506")
MsgBox(res)
```

But, I get this error :(

```
"Only single dimension arrays are supported here"
```

Comment: Why not just use the dataset? Copying that to an array here is a profoundly bad idea.

Comment: Further to @JoelCoehoorn's point, databases are designed to do this, programming languages are [generally] not. Get the database to do the work you need - It will be more efficient, take advantages of indices and other optimisations and saves you loading a ton of irrelevant data into memory. Is there a valid reason to do this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamentally wrong approach - for a number of reasons

- You're treating ALL the data points as Strings
- You're not taking advantage of DB optimisations like indices
- You're loading data into memory that you're never going to use (at least int he example)

The Nicest way to do it would be with Linq-To-Entities:

```
Dim Record = MyDBContext.Discount_Items.Where(function(x) x.ItemCode = "FO1506").Single
Console.WriteLine(Record.discountitem_average);
```

If you're stuck with your current Data Access Layer, you need to modify the SQL being executed to only return the information you're interested in. Without more information, I can't provide decent example code but you want the SQL to end up looking like this...

```
SELECT  itemcode,
        discountitem_average,
        [Other fields],
FROM    MyDatabase.M
```

EDIT: To Clarify, there are a number of ways to access data in a database. The one I prefer is LINQ-To-Entities (Have a look through [this tutorial](http://naspinski.net/post/Getting-started-with-Linq-To-Entities.aspx)).

In short, you add a new Item to your project and point it at your database. This becomes your "Database Context" - it represents the database and that's how you run queries.

Project -> Add -> New Item...

Select `ADO.Net Entity Data Model` (Linq-To-Entities is almost Identical to Linq-To-Sql but more recent and better supported - use Entities until you know the difference)

Call it something like `MyDBContext`

When prompted, choose "Generate From Database" and point it at your database.

It's worth noting that the designer takes advantage of information in the database like [Foreign Key Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464.aspx) - So the better your database is designed, the better the model it will create.

Then, you refer to it in code as shown in my first example.

Comment: exactly what you say is what I need, but where it says MyDBcontext that you mean where I declare that variable, Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: because they occupy look for the code and get the average discount of the same array

Comment: Thanks for your reply I found the way to do what I needed to do, very friendly :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all `IndexOf` return int as index!

To get the index of string 
Try:

```
Dim i As int
Dim j As int
i = Array.IndexOf(invoice_discountitems.OfType(Of String)().ToArray(), "FO1506")
j = i MOD 100
i= i/100
MsgBox(i+" "+j)
```

(I use c# but I think it's not different)